# Arduino + Ethernet shield + Bluetooth HC-05

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, ethernet

I want to connect Arduino Uno via Bluetooth to other devices. And it works, until I added an ethernet shield.

This line breaks bluetooth At mode: `EthernetServer server(80);`

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  BTSerial.begin(38400); // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
}
```

Comment: What pins is `BTSerial` using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use pin 4, 10, 11, 12 and 13 when using a ethernet shield. So if you ar using one of these for SoftwareSerial, this is why.

Comment: I've found the same answer.
Thanks!